# Jsocks Command not supported

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, udp, tsocks

Exception:

```
Command not supported
        at net.sourceforge.jsocks.socks.Socks5Message.read(Socks5Message.java:162)
        at net.sourceforge.jsocks.socks.Socks5Message.<init>(Socks5Message.java:123)
        at net.sourceforge.jsocks.socks.Socks5Message.<init>(Socks5Message.java:108)
        at net.sourceforge.jsocks.socks.Socks5Proxy.formMessage(Socks5Proxy.java:245)
        at net.sourceforge.jsocks.socks.Proxy.exchange(Proxy.java:446)
        at net.sourceforge.jsocks.socks.Proxy.udpAssociate(Proxy.java:385)
        at net.sourceforge.jsocks.socks.Socks5DatagramSocket.<init>(Socks5DatagramSocket.java:110)
        at net.sourceforge.jsocks.socks.Socks5DatagramSocket.<init>(Socks5DatagramSocket.java:54)
         ...
```

Code where error is occurring:

```java
try(Socks5DatagramSocket socket = new Socks5DatagramSocket())/* error here */ ...
```

I am using jsocks only for the ability to send UDP data over a proxy, if there are any better alternatives I am also open.

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that you are creating your object will the default (no parameter) constructor. Even if `read` was a valid command, it wouldn't work if the socket is not connected to something

Comment: @ControlAltDel I am not reading data, only outputting data, that is all.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I tried with the parameter: `new Socks5DatagramSocket(proxy, 0, null)` and it returned the same error.

Comment: The read call is right there at the top of your stacktrace

Comment: To "I tried with the parameter..." I don't really know what the issue is. I'm just saying that trying to read when you haven't stated where to connect to doesn't sound right

Comment: I figured its similar to the datagramsocket object, instantly after the try with resource block I execute `socket.send(packet)`. There is not much documentation on this specific thing I am trying to do (send udp packets through proxy) and the source code is not documented so I am finding it really hard.

Comment: @ControlAltDel also, my DatagramPacket specifies where to send the data too: `packet = new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length, address, port);`